# How to add x-server & x-taggroups for ReDoc through drf-yasg

Tags: django, documentation, openapi, drf-yasg, redoc

I am using `drf-yasg` for documentation,I am using `redoc` and it's working great. But I want to add `x-server` and `x-taggroups`. I would like to set custom tags for views, and add them to their own taggroups, but I cannot find anything in the docs about this, how should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can include arbitrary extra data in your schema (such as `x-server` and `x-tagGroups` vendor extensions) by subclassing `OpenAPISchemaGenerator`.

```py
class MyOpenAPISchemaGenerator(OpenAPISchemaGenerator):
    
    def get_schema(self, request=None, public=False):
        # Get the Swagger object generated by the superclass
        swagger = super().get_schema(request, public)

        # Add any extra fields you want
        swagger['x-tagGroups']=[{
            'name': 'My Group 1',
            'tags': ['myTag1', 'myTag2']
        },{
            'name': 'My Group 2',
            'tags': ['myTag1', 'myTag2', 'myTag3']
        }]
        return swagger
```

Then, make sure you provide your custom generator class when getting a `SchemaView` class:

```py
schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
       title="Your API",
       default_version='v1',
       description="Your description",
    ),
    public=True,
    generator_class=MyOpenAPISchemaGenerator, # <--- Don't forget this
    permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny],
)
```